# new to C# and trying to retrieve data

Tags: c#, sql, database, webforms, ado

Error of name sensorvalue is not in the current context. But I have already declared the ID in the UserPage.aspx. And also, I have returned the datathriller below this function but in this function it is not referring as well

```
*codes in UserPage.aspx.cs file
 public partial class UserPage : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             DataSet dataThriller = GetDataThriller();   

             sensorvalue.DataSource = datathriller;      

             sensorvalue.DataBind();
         }      

         private DataSet GetDataThriller()
        {
        string sensorData =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["databaseforproject"].ConnectionString;     #databaseforproject is the database I am trying to retrieve data from

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sensorData))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT sensorvalue FROM sensors WHERE 
sensortype="temperature_sensor" ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1", conn); 
                #selecting the last row of data where the column is sensorvalue from sensors table 
in ADO database where the column name sensortype is "temperature_sensor". And yes I am having problem putting in the sensortype="temperature sensor"

                DataSet datathriller = new DataSet();

                cmd.Fill(datathriller);

                return datathriller;
            }
        }


}




 *codes in UserPage.aspx file
 <div class="num"> <sup>o</sup>C</div>
 <asp:Label ID="sensorvalue" runat="serverText='<%#Eval("sensorvalue") %>'></asp:Label> 





*#trying to put the last row of data from the databaseforproject into my webform where the sensor 
value will be displayed*
```

Comment: FYI if you're new to C# & ASP.NET then, if you have any choice in the matter, I really wouldn't bother to learn WebForms - it's a legacy platform and better alternatives for developing web applications with C#/ASP.NET now exist (e.g. Razor pages, MVC, even Blazor now too)

Comment: I would test the Command Text (the select statement) in SQL Server Management Studio and get desired results in SSMS before trying in your code.

Comment: I'd suggest debugging to step through, line by line, and verify that everything is working as expected.  Then you can narrow down exactly when things start going wrong.

Comment: What SQL database type are you connecting to? If its Azure SQL or SQL Server it doesn't support LIMIT